# URL Captured Argument Django Saying Arguments Not Matching

Tags: python, django

Hi I am attempting to solve something really simple but I just cant figure out what's wrong, so I was hoping someone can see the error in my ways!

Here is the URLpattern:

```
url(r'^custserv/(\d{10})/(?P<page>\w+)/', views.analytics),
```

Here is the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='csrlogin/')
def analytics(request, number, page):
    print(request)
    context = RequestContext(request)
    ...
```

I give it the following link: http://***.com/custserv/9495555555/main/

However, an exception is thrown before I can even hit "print(request)"

> TypeError at /custserv/9495555555/main/
>   analytics() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://***/custserv/9495555555/main/
>   Django Version: 1.6.2
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   analytics() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>   Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 22
>   Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.8

Im pretty sure all of this is correct...but there has to be SOMETHING that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated!

PS: no other urlpattern is accessing "views.analytics"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not name the first capture group. Try changing it to:

```
url(r'^custserv/(?P<number>\d{10})/(?P<page>\w+)/', views.analytics),
```

Comment: and here's an explanation why you have to use either all named groups or all unnamed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#the-matching-grouping-algorithm